# Main content overlaps with right margin while trying to convert HTML to PDF with iText (c#)

Tags: c#, itext

I'm trying to convert html to pdf with iText library,  but while the pdf creation works well, the margins aren't.

I try to manually set the margins, but it seems the program not only ignores me, but worse, the main content overlaps the right side as you can see in the image

[image]

Here is a part of my code (cabecera is the string where html is located)

Main page

```
string file = string.Format("{0}LEGO_{1}_{2}_{3}_{4}_{5}.pdf",Constants.WebConfig.urlCopiaPdf, fecha.Day, fecha.Month, fecha.Year, fecha.Hour, fecha.Minute);
            string fileWeb = string.Format("{0}LEGO_{1}_{2}_{3}_{4}_{5}.pdf", Constants.WebConfig.urlCopiaPdfWeb, fecha.Day, fecha.Month, fecha.Year, fecha.Hour, fecha.Minute);
            string fileHTML = string.Format("{0}LEGO_{1}_{2}_{3}_{4}_{5}.html",Constants.WebConfig.urlCopiaPdf, fecha.Day, fecha.Month, fecha.Year, fecha.Hour, fecha.Minute);
            //string file = string.Format("c:\\docs\\LEGO{0}_{1}_{2}_{3}_{4}.pdf", fecha.Day, fecha.Month, fecha.Year, fecha.Hour, fecha.Minute);

            StringReader sr = new StringReader(cabecera);
            Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 40f, 40f, 60f, 20f);
            pdfDoc.SetMarginMirroring(false);
            HeaderAndFooter PageEventHandler = new HeaderAndFooter();               

            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, new FileStream(file, FileMode.Create));
            writer.PageEvent = PageEventHandler;
            writer.SetMargins(40f, 40f, 60f, 20f);
            writer.SetMarginMirroring(false);
            pdfDoc.Open();
            iTextSharp.tool.xml.XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, pdfDoc, sr);
            pdfDoc.Close();
```

Yes, I duplicated the setmargins, and setmarginmirroring, I was just trying if anything would work...I even tried creating a PdfPageEventHelper and write the following code as a test

```
public class HeaderAndFooter : PdfPageEventHelper
{
    public HeaderAndFooter()
        : base()
    {
    }


    public override void OnEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
    {
        PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;
        ColumnText.ShowTextAligned(cb, Element.ALIGN_CENTER, new Phrase(String.Format("dsadsadsadsad", writer.PageNumber)), (document.Right - 40), (document.Bottom - document.Top) / 2, 0);
    }
}
```

But nothing works...Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. I think you aren't getting any answers because people can't reproduce the problem. Problems that can't be reproduced are very hard to fix because no one knows what to fix.

Comment: We put the issue aside for something in higuer priority, but today i worked again with the problem and...voila! it seems the html wasn't well formed. After fixing it works perfectly 

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end my problem was the html I was using to create the PDF wasn't well formed (it didn't have an html, head and body tags,the template wasn't mine but...I should checked it before ask anything ), so after adding what it needs works perfectly well.